# Lifting on ${\scr L}^p$

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

For $1\le p<\infty$, let ${\scr L}^p(\mu)$ be the vector space of $p$-integrable functions on a locally compact space $X$ with Radon measure $\mu$ and let $L^p(\mu)$ be the usual space of equivalence classes $[f]$ of members of ${\scr L}^p(\mu)$ under $\mu$-a.e. equality. Is there a linear mapping $\psi:{\scr L}^p(\mu)\to {\scr L}^p(\mu)$ such that (a) $[\psi(f)]=[f]$ and (b) $[f]=[g]$ implies $\psi(f)=\psi(g)$?  [Tulcea](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1965-71-06/S0002-9904-1965-11407-0/S0002-9904-1965-11407-0.pdf) in footnote 6 says that "by a convenient splitting" one can obtain such a mapping in the case where $X$ is compact, but it's not obvious to me how that's supposed to work.

Comment: How is this different than the abstract problem:  Given a vector space $V$ and a linear subspace $W$, there exists a  linear subspace $W_1$ with $W \cap W_1 = \{0\}$ and $V = W + W_1$.  (Every short exact sequence splits.) Proof by choosing Hamel bases. ??  In this problem, take $W$ to be the a.e. zero functions.  To make this question interesting, perhaps you want more conditions, such as support of $\mu$ is $X$ and then require $\psi(f) = f$ for continuous $f$.

Comment: Ah, now it IS obvious. :-) BTW, the interesting additional condition that Tulcea considers is $\psi(f) \ge 0$ if $f\ge 0$, and he proves that if $\mu$ is diffuse (zero on singletons), you can't satisfy it.